# Exporting Mongo Db database collection to a json file

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am new to Mongodb with express js,I want a url
e.g URL /users/backup - Should read the records in mongodb collection users and export to json file and place in public/backup folder of application or should download to the localsystem..
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the nodeJs inbuilt `child_process` which enables us to access Operating System functionalities by running any system command inside a, well, child process.
Read more about it here on this very informative post. [Child Process](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/node-js-child-processes-everything-you-need-to-know-e69498fe970a/)

You can then run the `spawn` child process to run any command in your Operating System, where NodeJs is currently running.

Example:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
spawn('mongodump', [`--uri=${MONGODB_URL}`, `--collection=${COLLECTION_NAME}`, `--out=${DESTINATION_FOLDER}`])
```

This will dump your desired collection in the destination folder you set.

Coming to your request on using this in an URL, you can put the above code in a method and make an API endpoint say `/users/backup` which calls this method.